# How does associative arrays work in awk?

Tags: awk

I wanted to remove duplicate lines from a file based on a column. A quick search let me [this page](http://blog.midnightmonk.com/365/linux/awk-command-to-remove-duplicate-lines-based-on-fields.shtml) which had the following solution:

```
awk '!x[$1]++' filename
```

It works, but I am not sure how it works. I know it uses associate arrays in `awk` but I am not able to infer anything beyond it.

*Update*:

Thanks everyone for the explanation. With my new knowledge, I have wrote a [blog post](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/remove-duplicate-lines-based-on-a-field) with further explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That awk script `!x[$1]++` fills an array named `x`.  Suppose the first word (`$1` refers to the first word in a line of text) in a line of text is `line1`. It effectively results in this operation on the array:

```
x["line1"]++
```

The "index" (the key) of the array is the text encountered in the file (`line1` in this example), and the value associated with that key is an integer that is incremented by 1.

When a unique line of text is encountered, the current value of the array is zero, which is then post-incremented to 1.  The `not` operator `!` evaluates to non-zero (true) for each new unique line of text and so prints it.  The next time the same value is encountered, the value in the array is non-zero and so the `not` operation results in zero (false), so the line is not printed.

A less "clever" way of writing the same thing (but possibly more clear and less fun) would be this:

```
{
if (x[$1] == 0 ) 
   print
x[$1]++
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if the `awk` expression is going to return true, then the line will be printed and we don't have to explicitly call print? And also `x` here is just a variable name which can be replaced with anything else right?